# yii2 how to prevent swiftmailer from sending email to spam folder

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer, spam

How to prevent swiftmailer from sending email to the spam folder
I'm using it like this:

```
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
          ->setFrom($sender_email)
          ->setTo($reciver)
          ->setSubject($subject)
          ->setTextBody($body)
          ->setHtmlBody($hml)
          ->send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some header

[Reference](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/issues/6)

```
$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose(...);
$message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('name', 'value');
```

and also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995620/how-to-use-the-swiftmailer-in-yii2?rq=1)