# Email on Yii2 Advanced

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to know how to send an email when any user registers on the Yii2 Advanced app.

Here is information about it http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html, but i don't know how to do it. Can someone help me, please? Here is the directory too.

[image]

Comment: this link may help you [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995620/how-to-use-the-swiftmailer-in-yii2) OR [another link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/656/how-to-send-emails-using-smtp/)