# Email notification after "insert into" command is triggered for a particular table in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to find a way to implement an email notification functionality whenever a record is updated in the `kf_notifications` table. The email notification should be sent to the email address that corresponds to the `user_id` in the nofications table withinin the new updated record. Email ID is stored in a different table named `kf_users`

**Controller:**

```
 public function actionNotification()
{
    $uid = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

    if(isset($_GET['new'])) {
        //get new notifications
        $html = Yii::$app->Kiduchi->show_notification($uid);
    }
    else{
        //get all notifications
        $html = Yii::$app->Kiduchi->show_notification($uid,'all');
    }

    //update is_viewed
    $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
    $command = $connection->createCommand("UPDATE kf_notifications SET is_viewed=1 where user_id='$uid'");
    $command->execute();

    return $this->render('notification', ['html' => $html]);
}
```

**kf_notification (model):**

```
class Notifications extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'kf_notifications';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['visible_all', 'user_id', 'text', 'is_viewed'], 'required'],
        [['user_id', 'is_viewed'], 'integer'],
        [['text'], 'string'],
        [['created_on'], 'safe'],
        [['visible_all'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}
```

Comment: do mark the answer as correct if it worked for you

Comment: i will definately do so, please also share the code to send the email. Thank you

Comment: well, that can be easily found on the yiiDocs [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing) and provides you all the information to set up and configure the `SwiftMailer` moreover you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995620/how-to-use-the-swiftmailer-in-yii2) that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your title of the question and the body of the question are asking 2 different things? which one you are asking, send email on `update` or `insert`? Anyway, I assume that you want it on `update` of a record/row.

You can override `afterSave()` inside the model `kf_notifications`, it takes `$insert` and `$changedAttributes` parameters which hold boolean (for `$insert` | `true` or `false` depending if it is `insert` or `update` operation performed).

i assume that you have the code to send the email, so I will add the method to override the `afterSave()` and use `$this->senEmail()` as the reference to your email function.

It would be better if you add a relation inside your `kf_notifications` table like below.

```
public function getUser() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

**Note: please update the model name for the User if it is with some other name with complete namespace**

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

     //if it as update and some attributes were actually changed 
    //then send email to the user

    if (!$insert && !empty($changedAttributes)) {

        $userEmail=$this->user->email;
        $subject='Notification';
        $message=$this->text;

        //send email 
        $this->sendEmail($userEmail,$subject,$message);
    }
}
```

If you want to send on `insert` then change the check in the above code from

```
if (!$insert && !empty($changedAttributes)) {
```

to

```
if ($insert) {
```